# Fastest way to iterate through JSON string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have been using $.each of the jQuery framework to iterate through a JSON string that I receive via an AJAX call. Now this string is sometimes quite huge and as a result IE6/7/8 crawl as a result.

I am wondering if there is a faster way to iterate through the entire data.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How are you iterating through it? Are you parsing it, or are you evaling it? Do you need just certain parts?

Comment: some good clientside parsing & performance tips from [flickr](http://code.flickr.com/blog/2009/03/18/building-fast-client-side-searches/)

Comment: What is the structure of this json..? just a huge object or a huge array of objects..?

Answer (score 1):

How about using the regular javascript functions?

If for example you have a JSON object with items in them, you could just eval the JSON string to convert it to javascript objects, and iterate over them using 'for (i in object)'.

Comment: I assume Alec is using the json dataType in the xhr call therefore jquery will be eval'ing the response.

Answer (score 1):

Hope to be still in time!

How about a simple -for-?

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].property = 'todo';
}
```

Otherwise -for in-

```
var mycars = [{name:'Ferrari'}, {name:'BMW'}];
for (i in mycars)
{
    document.write(mycars[i].name + "<br />");
}
```

Here is the complete answer: [How do I iterate over a JSON structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-structure)