# understanding JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

JSON array :

```
var json_array = [
                 { "A" : "1" }, 
                 { "B" : "2" }
                  ];
```

How can I make a JS function that acts on every element of the array? Like..

```
$.each(json_array, function() { ...
```

Comment: That isn't a valid JSON object.

Comment: Why do you have curly brackets around the array?

Comment: Exactly as you have suggested.

Comment: just decode it and there you go...Or if you're receiving it from a `getJSON` AJAX request, you don't even have to do that.

Comment: I know I'm close but could you help me visualize it?

Comment: How do you decode a JSON array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-to-iterate-over-a-json-structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions.

1. JSON is just text.  You have an actual *JavaScript* array, <s>once you remove the outer curly braces from your code</s>.
2. Don't use JQuery for this.  The plain old JavaScript `forEach` already works on regular arrays, which is, what I think, you want.

**ADDENDUM**

Using JavaScript's `forEach`:

```
var a = [
    {"A": "1"},
    {"B": "2"}
];

a.forEach(function(x) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(x));
});
```

If you have an old browser (IE <= 8), replace the `forEach` call with (suggestion due to Asad):

```
for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i += 1) {
    // do something with the element object
}
```

JQuery's `each` is for jQuery objects.

​

Comment: forEach isn't cross browser compatible, so you could either shim or use the more generic `for(counter initialisation; counter condition; counter increment)` structure

Comment: Strictly speaking this is true, but looking at http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/ the only browser that doesn't support it is IE <= 8.

Comment: Many people would dispute the browserness of IE <= 8 :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use jQuery, then why don't you just loop the array?

```
for (i = 0; i < json_array.length; i++)
{
   var item = json_array[i]; // this is { "A": 1 }
   for (element in item)
   {
       // element is "A", item[element] is 1
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the jQuery `each`

```
$.each(json_array, function( index, item) {
   alert( item.A};
})
```

The keys in each object within the array are typically the same which your demo isn't so this would work for:

```
var json_array = [
                 { "A" : "1" }, 
                 { "A" : "2" }
                  ];
```