# How to iterate over json objects and bind with html elemnts.?

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I need to iterate over the JSON objects coming from my controller and bind the data to the html elements. When I alert I am getting objects.
How can  I iterate over these objects to get access  to individual data, so that I can append it to the html elements?

I have tried the following codes. I just have a few items here for a demo, the actual array is very big.

My controller:

```
     public function grid_view_ajax_function()
            {       
                $contacts_details="";
                $this->load->model('contact_model');
                $contacts_details= $this->contact_model->get_all_contacts();
                $result = array();
                $data   = array();
                foreach ($contacts_details as $row_data){
                $data['id']                  =$row_data['contact_id'];
                $data['image']               =$row_data['image'];
                $data['name']                =$row_data['first_name'];
                $data['last_name']           =$row_data['last_name'];    
                array_push($result, $data);

                }
                echo json_encode(array('data' => $result));
            }
```

main.js file to iterate over the objects in jquery:

```
         $.getJSON(global_base_url + "contact/grid_view_ajax_function",function(data)
            {
            var div_data = ''; 
                $.each(data,function(i,data)
                {       

    div_data +='<div class="col-xl-15" data-id="'+data.index+'"><div class="panel"><div class="panel-heading"><img src="../asset/'+data.picture+'" class="img-responsive desaturate" /></div><div class="panel-body"><div class="name">'+data.name+'</div><div class="email">'+data.email+'</div><div>';
                });
```

JSON data:

```
{
  "data":[
   {
    "id":"1",
    "image":"4.jpg",
    "name":"Mack ",
    "last_name":"Jack",
    "title":"Adminstration",
    "city":"London"
   },
  {
    "id":"2",
    "image":"person-list.png",
    "name":"Renia",
    "last_name":"Jack",
    "title":"Archetectuer"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Is this `PHP`? If so, tag `PHP`. "*When I alert I am getting objects*" - where are you alerting BTW?

Comment: @TJ,I am alerting like   $.each(data,function(i,data)
                {  alert(data); }

Comment: Then please add it in the question, to indicate that you have access to the data. BTW, i don't see `index`, `picture`, `email` etc in the json..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over a JSON structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate like

```js
//here ajax response object is assigned to data variable
var data = {"data":[{"id":"1","image":"4.jpg","name":"Mack ","last_name":"Jack","title":"Adminstration","city":"London"},{"id":"2","image":"person-list.png","name":"Renia","last_name":"Jack","title":"Archetectuer"}]};

var div_data = '';
$.each(data.data,function(i,data) {

  div_data += "<li>"+data.name+"</li>";
  
});
$("ul").html(div_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: How can i get the json data coming from my controleer in main .js.?

Comment: here a refers to data you got from ajax call

Comment: @mithun...its now showing error  lenght of undefined.

Comment: you can try running the code in the fiddle itself. doesnt show any error in consle. see the updated code as per your code in question.