# Iterating the json object

Tags: javascript, json

I am facing trouble iterating through a json object in plain javascript code. for loop or for each loop would be great but I am not able to loop it.

```
//I want output in format like 
{
 applicationGroupId:
 [
  treatmentIds
 ]
}
```

like;

```
{
    "879545457291368": [
        879545457291370
    ],
    "879545447124032": [
        879545447124036,
        879545447124034
    ]
}


<script>

var text = '{"treatmentApplicationGroupDataList": [{"applicationGroupId": 879545457291368,"treatments":[{"treatmentId": 879545457291370}]},{"applicationGroupId": 879545447124032,'+
           '"treatments": [{"treatmentId": 879545447124036 },{"treatmentId": 879545447124034}]}]}';

     var myObject = JSON.parse(text);

     for(var i in myObject){

   document.write(myObject.treatmentApplicationGroupDataList[0].applicationGroupId);
   document.write(myObject.treatmentApplicationGroupDataList[0].treatments[0].treatmentId);

   document.write(myObject.treatmentApplicationGroupDataList[1].applicationGroupId);
   document.write(myObject.treatmentApplicationGroupDataList[1].treatments[0].treatmentId);
   ocument.write(myObject.treatmentApplicationGroupDataList[1].treatments[1].treatmentId);

     }

</script>
```

So as you can see I am manually printing the result but not in for loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over a JSON structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-structure)

Comment: Not exactly, as i have already gone through this link before posting question. i have to iterate simply not key/value pair. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've tried to do in your example, you can user the for-in method:

```
var text = '{"treatmentApplicationGroupDataList": [{"applicationGroupId": 879545457291368,"treatments":[{"treatmentId": 879545457291370}]},{"applicationGroupId": 879545447124032,"treatments": [{"treatmentId": 879545447124036 },{"treatmentId": 879545447124034}]}]}';

var myObject = JSON.parse(text);

// Using the for-in method
for (treatmentListId in myObject.treatmentApplicationGroupDataList) {
    var curTreatmentList = myObject.treatmentApplicationGroupDataList[treatmentListId];

    console.log(curTreatmentList.applicationGroupId+": ");

    for (treatmentId in curTreatmentList.treatments) {
        console.log("=>"+curTreatmentList.treatments[treatmentId].treatmentId);
    }
}
```

Or you can use the [.forEach method](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach) :

```
myObject.treatmentApplicationGroupDataList.forEach(function(treatmentList){
    console.log(treatmentList.applicationGroupId+": ");
    treatmentList.treatments.forEach(function(treatment){
        console.log("=> "+treatment.treatmentId);
    });
});
```

More informations available here : [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good explanation for the forEach function that you can use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/4693496

Given your following object:

```
{
    "treatmentApplicationGroupDataList": [
        {
            "applicationGroupId": 879545457291368,
            "treatments":
                [
                    {
                        "treatmentId": 879545457291370
                    }
                ]
        },
        {
            "applicationGroupId": 879545447124032,
            "treatments": [
                {
                    "treatmentId": 879545447124036
                },
                {
                    "treatmentId": 879545447124034
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use the following function:

```
myObject.treatmentApplicationGroupDataList.forEach(function(item) {
    document.write(item.applicationGroupId);
    item.treatments.forEach(function(treatment) {
        document.write(treatment.treatmentId);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below code

```
var text = '{"treatmentApplicationGroupDataList": [{"applicationGroupId": 879545457291368,"treatments":[{"treatmentId": 879545457291370}]},{"applicationGroupId": 879545447124032,'+
           '"treatments": [{"treatmentId": 879545447124036 },{"treatmentId": 879545447124034}]}]}';

var myObject = JSON.parse(text);
var newObj = {};

for(var i in myObject['treatmentApplicationGroupDataList']){
    var appGroupId = myObject['treatmentApplicationGroupDataList'][i]['applicationGroupId'];
    newObj[appGroupId] = [];
    for(var j in myObject['treatmentApplicationGroupDataList'][i]['treatments'])
        newObj[appGroupId].push(myObject['treatmentApplicationGroupDataList'][i]['treatments'][j]['treatmentId'])
}

//newObj will contain the required Json.
```

**Explaination**:

The first `for` loop will iterate over the `treatmentApplicationGroupDataList` and then in that loop will get the `applicationGroupId` for this list and make a new Object for it with its `key` as the `applicationGroupId`  with a `value` as an `array` The next nested `for` loop will loop through all the `treatments` in that group to extract the `treatmentId` and to push them in the `array` created in the above for loop.