# How to display JSON data using ejs in html page?

Tags: json, node.js, ejs

I have a json data that contains so many objects and array of arrays how to    display this data using ejs in html. I tried like below.

```
<p><%- JSON.stringify(jsonData) %></p>
```

i am trying to retrieve the array values inside the json file,for example                 i  want to display the location code of departure airport under the flight segment array.we have upload under the screenshot.please give me the sample code for this using ejs. [image]

Comment: Paste example of jsonData.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over a JSON structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-structure)