# How would I go about iterating over this JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I'm pulling in the below json data from a database using ajax.

```
{"route":[{"latitude":-27.38851,"longitude":153.11606},{"latitude":-27.47577,"longitude":153.01693}]}
```

How would I got about iterating over it to get lat/long pairs to plot on a map?

Comment: reference route and loop over the array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over a JSON structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-structure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the JSON data to a variable, and loop through the `route` object like below:

```
var j = {"route":[{"latitude":-27.38851,"longitude":153.11606},{"latitude":-27.47577,"longitude":153.01693}]}

for(i=0; i<=j.route.length; i++){
  var thisRoute = j.route[i];   
}
```

Comment: Remark: This is simply iterating over a javascript array, not JSON data. But that probably is what @user1542125 wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try:

```
var j = {"route":[{"latitude":-27.38851,"longitude":153.11606},{"latitude":-27.47577,"longitude":153.01693}]};
for(var i= 0,len=j.route.length; i<len; i++){
  var lat = j.route[i].latitude;
  var long = j.route[i].longitude;
  console.log(lat+' '+long);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = {"route":[{"latitude":-27.38851,"longitude":153.11606},{"latitude":-27.47577,"longitude":153.01693}]};
var i = 0;
var lat, long;
var len=o.route.length; 
for(i,i<len; i++){
  lat = o.route[i].latitude;
  long = o.route[i].longitude;
  console.log(lat+' '+long);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full implementation of what you're trying to achieve:

[JSFIddle with a map](http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/573/)

```
  function createMarker(options) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);

        return marker;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < data.route.length; i++) {
        createMarker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.route[i].latitude, data.route[i].longitude),
            map: map

        });
```