# How to read JSON response from UDP broadcast

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read the UDP broadcast response from the code below. Two servers are found and the information is returned for both of them. What I want to do is make a dict for each response  but I can't seem to separate the individual responses. Can any one make some suggestions please?

```
import socket
import json

socket.setdefaulttimeout(.5)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, True)
s.sendto("D", ('255.255.255.255', 30303))

while True:
    response = s.recv(2048)
    response = json.loads(response)
    print response
```

This is the response:

```
{u'Product': u'OWServer_v2-Enet', u'Name': u'OWServer_v2-Enet_19',       u'IP': u'10.0.1.19', u'TCPIntfPort': u'0', u'HTTPPort': u'80', u'MAC': u'00-04-A3-B1-F1-86', u'Bootloader': u'POST', u'FWVer': u'1.44', u'NETBios': u'EDSOWSERVER19   '}
{u'Product': u'OWServer_v2-Enet', u'Name': u'OWServer_v2-Enet_20', u'IP': u'10.0.1.20', u'TCPIntfPort': u'0', u'HTTPPort': u'80', u'MAC': u'00-04-A3-C1-43-86', u'Bootloader': u'POST', u'FWVer': u'1.44', u'NETBios': u'EDSOWSERVER20   '}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Using your suggestions, if I have done it correctly, gives me ValueErrors.

```
buf = "" 

while True:
    buf = buf + s.recv(2048)
    resp = ''
    if "\n" in buf:
        resp, buf = buf.split("\n", 1)
        if resp:
            print json.loads(resp)

raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting property name", s, end - 1))
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 32 (char 32)
```

Comment: Have you tried [iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-structure)?  It's hard to be more helpful when I am not sure what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a separator, for example a newline, so you get a stream of [JSON-lines](http://jsonlines.org/). You can then split on newline and parse each item separately. But of course, you must add the newline on your own when sending the packets.

A JSON entry might span multiple packets and you have to manage packet segmentation on your own. When you do `s.recv(2048)`, you get up to 2048 bytes of data, which you need to store in buffer:

```
buf = buf + s.recv(2048)
```

Then split this buffer into full response and the rest:

```
resp = ''
if '\n' in buf:
    resp, buf = buf.split('\n', 1)
```

And then load the full response:

```
if resp:
    print json.loads(resp)
```

Comment: This is my problem, I can't see how to separate the lines. No matter what I try the two responses seem to come back as one.

Comment: I've edited to show how to use a recieve buffer. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Thanks much for your time. Yes it makes sense but I get a "NameError: name 'buf' is not defined", I have this as the first line after while True:

Comment: `buf` is a variable you have to declare first, yes.