# Looping over JSON key objects that doesn't have array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following JSON:

```
basket = {
    "Items": 3,
    "Item": {
          "iPhone 6": {
              "productId": 227,
         "url": "http://example.com/iphone6",
         "price": 299.99
           },
          "Solio Mono Solar Charger": {
          "productId": 655,
          "url": "http://website.com/solio_charger.html",
          "price": 29.95
           },
           "24 Month Warranty Package": {
             "productId": 681,
          "url": "http://website.com/24_month_warranty.html",
          "price": 129.95
           }
      },
    "Total": 459.89
}
```

I want to loop over the objects in `basket['Item']`, but the JSON does not inherently provide an array to do so, what is the best way to loop over the objects in `basket['item']`?

Comment: There's plenty of ways to do this - what have you tried?

Comment: You can check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-structure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all property names of object and then iterate it with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
 Object.keys(basket.Item).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(item);
      console.log(basket.Item[key]);
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `for...in` for that.

```
var obj = {
  cat: 'meow',
  dog: 'woof'
}

for (attr in obj) {
  console.log(attr + ': ' + obj[attr])
}
```

Which will appropriately log:

```
cat: meow
dog: woof
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bk1aotbh/) for your object.

You can also use Object.keys() but it's only supported in IE >= 9.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for in`:

```
for (var property in basket['Item']) {
    var value = basket['Item'][property];
    console.log(property + ':');
    console.dir(value);
}
```