# Parsing a json object of unkown depth, with unknown values, with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, json, recursion, foreach

Basically I will be calling a service that will return a json object with an unknown amount of parents, children, grandchildren, etc., all with unknown names.  Basically I just know it will be a JSON object, and I need to recursively parse through it with angular.ForEach().  I have only used recursion on a very basic level back in college, so I'm a bit out of my depth.  I need to be able to display these objects in a tree-like structure in html after parsing, as well.  Does anyone know of any good directives or anything of the sort that can help?  Many thanks.

Comment: have you tried any way, better add json so that I can help you

Comment: Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). The **JSON.parse()** method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this library in a very small project, not extensively. But there's a lot more to it than what I've used.

https://github.com/awendland/angular-json-tree

Basically, import and instantiate the library and use this for your HTML:

```
<json-tree object="jsonObject"></json-tree>
```

Depending on your specific needs (which you didn't state), you can use other properties - check the documentation for that.

As of [Styling](https://github.com/awendland/angular-json-tree#styling), they include a css file you can use. You're also free to extend or create your own from scratch.

I hope it helps!

Comment: A simpler solution, but less interactive, would be using native AngularJS stuff. My "debug" view is usually like this:
    <pre>{{ jsonObject | json }}</pre>

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is display it, you can use [angular-json-tree](https://github.com/awendland/angular-json-tree).

If you would like to programmatically iterate it, there are a number of ways to do it, but some of the best are already documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112609/632676

Note that if you are receiving a JSON string, you will have to convert it into an object via `JSON.parse(jsonString);`