# How do I iterate over a nested JSON during Ajax?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "draw": 0,
  "recordsTotal": 90,
  "recordsFiltered": 41,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "5",
      "art": "default/def2.jpg",
      "full_name": " ",
      "title": "Hellberg - The Girl | Atomik Remix",
      "tag": "music",
      "time": "2015-11-14",
      "": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "art": "default/def2.jpg",
      "full_name": "Simon Deoro",
      "title": "Tim McMorris-On (Single)",
      "tag": "dance,popular,",
      "time": "2015-11-14",
      "": ""
    },
    ...
   ]
}
```

I want to return all `id`'s inside `data`, so I tried this function:

```
function getPlaylist(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: baseUrl+"/playlist.php?id="+id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            var samples = JSON.parse( result );
            for (i in samples)
            {
              console.log(samples.data[i].id + "<br />");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

however I see this error from console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

I tried also this `for` loop (syntax error from console)

```
for(var i = 0; i < samples.data.length; i++)
{
    var product = samples.data[i];
    var productId = product.id;
    console.log(productId);
}
```

All I want is output `5, 8` (my `id`'s)

I'm not very familiar with JSON, so how can I access and iterate over my structure correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over a JSON structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`samples` needs to be `samples.data`.

```
function getPlaylist(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: baseUrl+"/playlist.php?id="+id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            var samples = JSON.parse( result );
            for (i in samples.data)
            {
              console.log(samples.data[i].id + "<br />");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: from console I see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: now I see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1`

Comment: hmmm... it should be working. Are you sure that the json returned is valid json?  Here is an example, like yours, but with dummy data: http://jsbin.com/jexujohiqe/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @NineCattoRules That means your server script isn't returning valid JSON. It's probably sending HTML before the JSON. Fix the script so it doesn't output anything except `echo json_encode(...);`

Comment: @NineCattoRules You could add `console.log(result)` as the first line in your success function. That should tell you what is being returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `map` function to transform the array to another array.

```js
 var dataJSON = {
      "draw": 0,
      "recordsTotal": 90,
      "recordsFiltered": 41,
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "art": "default/def2.jpg",
          "full_name": " ",
          "title": "Hellberg - The Girl | Atomik Remix",
          "tag": "music",
          "time": "2015-11-14",
          "": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "8",
          "art": "default/def2.jpg",
          "full_name": "Simon Deoro",
          "title": "Tim McMorris-On (Single)",
          "tag": "dance,popular,",
          "time": "2015-11-14",
          "": ""
        },
        
       ]
    };
        

var obj = dataJSON.data.map((currentValue) => currentValue.id);
console.log(obj);
```

In the ajax function, you can replace the code like this

```
function getPlaylist(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: baseUrl+"/playlist.php?id="+id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            var samples = JSON.parse( result );
            var idArray = samples.data.map(x => x.id);
            console.log(idArray);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you please show me how to do this on my Ajax request?