# Iterate through Array in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am generating a graph through JSON. I want to include every element of my Array in it. As you can see I am hard coding the array elements currently (relation[0], relation[1]). I want to iterate through the whole array. How ever, I obviously can't put for loop in JSON. If I try to include only array itself (relation), my graph wont generate because the whole array is wrapped with [ ] brackets. 
So instead of adding relation[0], relation[1], ..... I'd like that to be added automatically based on array size.

```
this.graph.fromJSON({
  "cells": [{
      "type": "qad.Question",
      "size": {"width": 201.8984375, "height": 125},
      "optionHeight": 30,
      "questionHeight": 45,
      "paddingBottom": 20,
      "minWidth": 150,
      "inPorts": [{"id": "in", "label": "In"}],
      "outPorts": [],
      "position": {"x": 300, "y": 38},
      "angle": 0,
      "question": objectName2,
      "options": objectCol2,
      "id": "1849d917-8a43-4d51-9e99-291799c144db",
      "z": 2
    }, relation[0],relation[1]
  ]
});
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-structure

Comment: How about you create an array with necessary config values and then concat relations into it. `var params = [{...}]; ..."cells": params.concat(relation),..`

Comment: @Rajesh thanks for the idea. I'll try it.

Comment: @Rajesh now the problem is when I want to add that array to this method this.graph.fromJSON(JSON.stringify(params)). The output is yet again wrapped with [ ], therefore it cant be parsed as valid JSON. ["cells": .... ]

Comment: `[cells: ...]` is not valid. It should be `{ cells: [...]}`

Comment: I fixed it.  I was creating var array = [ { cells: [...] } ], instead of var array = { cells: [...] }

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  var obj = json[i];

  console.log(obj.id);
}
```

Comment: Please add explanation

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: [How do I iterate over a JSON structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078118/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-structure)

```js
var arr = [ {"id":"10", "class": "child-of-9"}, {"id":"11", "class": "child-of-10"}];
    
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  document.write("<br><br>array index: " + i);
  var obj = arr[i];
  for (var key in obj){
    var value = obj[key];
    document.write("<br> - " + key + ": " + value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var relation= [relation[0],relation[1]];
var obj = {
  "cells": [{
      "type": "qad.Question",
      "size": {"width": 201.8984375, "height": 125},
      "optionHeight": 30,
      "questionHeight": 45,
      "paddingBottom": 20,
      "minWidth": 150,
      "inPorts": [{"id": "in", "label": "In"}],
      "outPorts": [],
      "position": {"x": 300, "y": 38},
      "angle": 0,
      "question": objectName2,
      "options": objectCol2,
      "id": "1849d917-8a43-4d51-9e99-291799c144db",
      "z": 2
    }
  ]
};
this.graph.fromJSON(obj.cells.concat(relation));
```