# Get information from varying objects in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I have this code (which is variant thought the time) in JSON

```
{
  "5780": {
    "app": "Bye",
    "name": "Hello World",
    "surname": "Friend"
  },
  "6654": {
    "app": "Hello",
    "name": "Hi",
    "surname": "godbye"
  }
}
```

I want to get the information from each section (for example the "app" section) an insert in a js variable. The problem is that the object title (5780 & 6654) change will change (at the same time, the sections information). So I need something like `section[1].app = jsvariable1`

Comment: You want to iterate over the JSON object. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1078118/2291

Comment: Is that a valid json?

Comment: @Hackerman It is not exactly perfectly valid JSON; it is missing some commas and closing marks, but we get the idea—it is close enough.

Comment: Now it is a valid one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your json is not valid so you have to check it(as i did in the code below) . So here's what i did :

```js
var sections = {
  "5780": {
    "app": "Bye",
    "name": "Hello World",
    "surname": "Friend",
  },

  "6654": {
    "app": "Hello",
    "name": "Hi",
    "surname": "godbye",
  }

};


var index = [];

//setting the index array
for (var x in sections) {
  index.push(x);
}

console.log(sections[index[0]].app)
console.log(sections[index[1]].app)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop

```
   var obj = {
      "5780": {
        "app": "Bye",
        "name": "Hello World",
        "surname": "Friend",
      },
      "6654": {
        "app": "Hello",
        "name": "Hi",
        "surname": "godbye",
      }
    }

    for (var key in obj) {
      console.log(obj[key].app);
    }
```

This will log

```
Bye
Hello
```

If you want to update the value of app:

```
for (var key in obj) {
      obj[key].app = "New Name";
}
```

The key is the `5780` and `6654`