# How to Get the JSON Objects' Name in an JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I need to get the values "channelA" and "channelB", which are the object names.

**JSON file:**

```
[
    {
        "channelA": {
            "programmes": [
                {
                    "start_utc": 1522208700,
                    "stop_utc": 1522209600,
                },
                {
                    "start_utc": 1522209600,
                    "stop_utc": 1522210800,
                }
            ]    
        }
   },
   {
      "channelB": {
          "programmes": [
               {
                  "start_utc": 1522256700,
                  "stop_utc": 1522260800                     
               },
               {
                  "start_utc": 152229000,
                  "stop_utc": 1522318900,                     
               }
           ]
       }
   }
]
```

I am storing the JSON in a value called epg, and iterating through epg with:

```
for (var k = 0; k < epg.length; k++) {          
    console.log(_epg[k]);   
}
```

[image]

I need to compare the name of the object with another variable (channelId):

```
for (var k = 0; k < _epg.length; k++) {
    if (channelId == epg[k]) {
       console.log(_epg[k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the key inside each object of the array and compare with the `channelId`:

```js
var _epg = [
    {
        "channelA": {
            "programmes": [
                {
                    "start_utc": 1522208700,
                    "stop_utc": 1522209600,
                },
                {
                    "start_utc": 1522209600,
                    "stop_utc": 1522210800,
                }
            ]    
        }
   },
   {
      "channelB": {
          "programmes": [
              {
                  "start_utc": 1522256700,
                  "stop_utc": 1522260800                     
              },
              {
                  "start_utc": 152229000,
                  "stop_utc": 1522318900,                     
               }
           ]
       }
   }
];

var channelId = 'channelB';
for(var k=0; k<_epg.length; k++){
    var key = Object.keys(_epg[k])[0];
    if (channelId == key){
       console.log(_epg[k]);         
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want those names you can simply [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over the array and return the first element from the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) array:

```js
const data = [{"channelA":{"programmes":[{"start_utc":1522208700,"stop_utc":1522209600,},{"start_utc":1522209600,"stop_utc":1522210800,}]}},{"channelB":{"programmes":[{"start_utc":1522256700,"stop_utc":1522260800},{"start_utc":152229000,"stop_utc":1522318900,}]}}]

const out = data.map(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0]);
console.log(out);
```

**RESULT**

```
[
  "channelA",
  "channelB"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys()` method for this:

```js
let myArr = [
    {
        "channelA": {
            "programmes": [
                {
                    "start_utc": 1522208700,
                    "stop_utc": 1522209600,
                },
                {
                    "start_utc": 1522209600,
                    "stop_utc": 1522210800,
                }
            ]    
        }
   },
   {
      "channelB": {
          "programmes": [
              {
                  "start_utc": 1522256700,
                  "stop_utc": 1522260800                     
              },
              {
                  "start_utc": 152229000,
                  "stop_utc": 1522318900,                     
               }
           ]
       }
   }
]    

for (let item of myArr) {
  for (let key of Object.keys(item)) {
    if (key == "channelA" || key == "channelB") console.log(key + ": ", item[key])
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 1):

Since keys are uniques, you can find the object using the function `filter` as follow:

*I've added two `channeldB` to illustrate*

```js
var array = [    {        "channelA": {            "programmes": [                {                    "start_utc": 1522208700,                    "stop_utc": 1522209600,                },                {                    "start_utc": 1522209600,                    "stop_utc": 1522210800,                }            ]            }   },   {      "channelB": {          "programmes": [               {                  "start_utc": 1522256700,                  "stop_utc": 1522260800                                    },               {                  "start_utc": 152229000,                  "stop_utc": 1522318900,                                    }           ]       }   },   {      "channelB": {          "programmes": [               {                  "start_utc": 15232256700,                  "stop_utc": 1599990800                                    },               {                  "start_utc": 992229000,                  "stop_utc": 1520910900,                                    }           ]       }   }];

var channelId = "channelB";
var found = array.filter((a) => a[channelId]);
console.log(found);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Object.entries method to get those values.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 0):

You might want to iterate over the json:

```html
var arr = [ {"id":"10", "class": "child-of-9"}, {"id":"11", "classd": "child-of-10"}];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var obj = arr[i];
    for (var key in obj){
        var attrName = key;
        var attrValue = obj[key];
        console.log(attrName + " " + attrValue)
    }
}
```

This will produce the following output:

- "id 10"
- "class child-of-9"
- "id 11"
- "classd child-of-10"

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112609/3504189